# Block HTTP traffic on ingress in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

Following the example at `https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/gce/README.md` my ingress.yaml looks like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-app
  rules:
  - host: t.my-app.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: 80
```

I expect it to block all http traffic, but unfortunately this is not happening! I am still getting 443 and 80 both! I have spent hours on hours trying to get if there is anything wrong with the annotation, but I simply cannot find any way to deduce that!